# Difference between implicits and import statements

Tags: scala, import, implicit

Every spark program has this line `import spark.implicits._`. When I looked online to understand the use of "implicits" in scala, I got this definition:

```
Scala "implicits" allow you to omit calling methods or referencing variables directly but instead rely on the compiler to make the connections for you
```

I understand the definition but it brings me the below doubts.

Isn't it the same with any other import statement ? Every import statement would bring the functions/options/methods we would like to use them in the code.
If `implicits` are different to regular import statement, what do they bring to the table and how are they different ?
Could anyone explain the real use case of `implicits` parameters & functions 
in scala ?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it the same with any other import statement ?

It is. `implicits` in `spark.implicits` is just a name, and

> import spark.implicits._

is only unusual because it imports *members of an instance*, which many other languages with something like `import` can't do (but Scala can).

If you look at [docs for `implicits`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$implicits$) you'll see its members are marked as `implicit` which is what actually makes them implicit.